# How to get transaction details on eBay API

Tags: ebay-api

To get Seller Transactions from eBay I use API function [`GetSellerTransactions`](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/GetSellerTransactions.html)

It returns me `TransactionType` array in `TransactionArray` property of the response (`GetSellerTransactionsResponseType`)

In that array I have transactions from eBay.

Is there a way to get one `TransactionType` object when I have eBay Transaction ID value (string like: 12345678900)?

Appreciate with any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems it's impossible to do, you can get [GetOrderTransactions](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetOrderTransactions.html)

but you need to know OrderIDs, ItemIDs, or SKU values